# How can I detect failure to load an image in Elm

Tags: elm

How can I detect that an image was failed to be load in Elm?

I use `img [ src "/path/to/image" ]` and would like to know if the image failed to load.
In plan old JavaScript I would register to `onError` event of `img` but I don't see `onError` in Elm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Html.Events.on`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0/Html-Events#on) to capture an image load error.

You will need a `Msg` value to indicate that the image failed. Here I'll call that `ImageError`:

```elm
img [ src "/path/to/image", on "error" (Json.Decode.succeed ImageError) ] []
```

The use of `Json.Decode.succeed` may look confusing in this context (after all, you're trying to capture an error, so what is `succeed` doing there?), but that's just part of the JSON decoding package. It basically means to ignore the error javascript value passed as the first parameter by the DOM event and use the `ImageError` `Msg`.

[Here is an example of capturing the error event](https://ellie-app.com/3D7kv5wWVzXa1/1).

[And here is another example which captures both the `error` and `load` events](https://ellie-app.com/3D7s7xQ6yS5a1/0). You can change the image src to a good or bad URL to see what happens in either case.

Comment: I mistakenly look in the Html.Attribute file instead of events.

Comment: @Chad Gilbert but how could I retry loading the image from the same URL onerror?