# Elm: attribute "onerror" adds "data-onerror" attribute instead

Tags: elm

In Elm I have a simple image, and I want it to be replaced by some 'missing' image onerror. So I added an "onerror" attribute:

```
img
    [ src "broken-link.png"
    , attribute "onerror" "this.onerror=null;this.src='missing.png';"
    ] []
```

However, when I look at the generated html, the img doesn't get an `onerror` attribute, but rather gets an `data-onerror`, and ofcourse this doesn't work.

Why is this? And how do I fix it?

Here is a little example I made with my friend Bulbasaur to illustrate the problem: https://ellie-app.com/3Yn8Y6Rmvrqa1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Why is this?

This seems to be a built-in undocumented safety feature of Elm.

Checking source code of Elm, `Html.attribute` is defined as ([source](https://github.com/elm/html/blob/97f28cb847d816a6684bca3eba21e7dbd705ec4c/src/Html/Attributes.elm#L183))

```
attribute : String -> String -> Attribute msg
attribute =
    VirtualDom.attribute
```

and `VirtualDom.attribute` is defined as ([source](https://github.com/elm/virtual-dom/blob/5a5bcf48720bc7d53461b3cd42a9f19f119c5503/src/VirtualDom.elm#L181)):

```
attribute : String -> String -> Attribute msg
attribute key value =
    Elm.Kernel.VirtualDom.attribute
        (Elm.Kernel.VirtualDom.noOnOrFormAction key)
        (Elm.Kernel.VirtualDom.noJavaScriptOrHtmlUri value)
```

Your attribute name `onclick` is passed to `Elm.Kernel.VirtualDom.noOnOrFormAction` which is defined in JavaScript as ([source](https://github.com/elm/virtual-dom/blob/5a5bcf48720bc7d53461b3cd42a9f19f119c5503/src/Elm/Kernel/VirtualDom.js#L282)):

```
function _VirtualDom_noOnOrFormAction(key)
{
    return /^(on|formAction$)/i.test(key) ? 'data-' + key : key;
}
```

So if attribute name starts with `on`, or is string `formAction`, then it is renamed to be a data-attribute.

## How do I fix it?

One way I know how to fix this is to write the code in Elm without JavaScript. Here's [full working example](https://ellie-app.com/3YnVzLLYpgNa1) with main parts copied below: (This is based on accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864043/how-can-i-detect-failure-to-load-an-image-in-elm) about detecting image load failure.)

1) Keep current URL in model

```
type alias Model =
    { src : String
    }

init : Model
init =
    { src = "http://example.com" }
```

2) Change event handler to send Elm message on image load error

```
img
    [ src model.src
    , on "error" (Json.Decode.succeed ImageError)
    , alt "Should be Bulbasaur"
    ] []
```

3) Change URL in `update` on error

```
update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case msg of
        ImageError ->
            { model
                | src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/1.png"
            }
```

Answer (score 7):

I'd solve this problem by writing a [custom event handler](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/html/latest/Html-Events#on) for image load error event. The custom handler will be look a like:

```
onImageLoadError : msg -> Html.Attribute msg
onImageLoadError message =
    on "error" (JD.succeed message)
```

I'll define the `Model`, `Msg` as below:

```
type Msg
    = ImageLoadError


type alias Model =
    ImageSrc
```

I'll also define a custom type to wrap the good and default url.

```
type ImageSrc
    = Good String
    | Default String
```

The `onImageLoadError` will be fired and send the `ImageLoadError` msg to the `update` function, and the `update` function will then set the default url as:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case msg of
        ImageLoadError ->
            Default "https://developer.mozilla.org/static/img/web-docs-sprite.22a6a085cf14.svg"
```

And here is the full runnable code:

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Browser
import Html exposing (Html, div, img, text)
import Html.Attributes exposing (alt, src)
import Html.Events exposing (on)
import Json.Decode as JD


type Msg
    = ImageLoadError


type ImageSrc
    = Good String
    | Default String


type alias Model =
    ImageSrc


update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case msg of
        ImageLoadError ->
            Default "https://developer.mozilla.org/static/img/web-docs-sprite.22a6a085cf14.svg"


imageSrcVal : ImageSrc -> String
imageSrcVal src =
    case src of
        Good url ->
            url

        Default url ->
            url


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ div [] [ text "Broken image, that should be replaced by Bulbasaur: " ]
        , img
            [ src (imageSrcVal model)
            , alt "Should be Bulbasaur"
            , onImageLoadError ImageLoadError
            ]
            []
        , div [] [ text "instead it does nothing, and the 'onerror' attribute is 'data-onerror' (use inspect element to see)" ]
        ]


onImageLoadError : msg -> Html.Attribute msg
onImageLoadError message =
    on "error" (JD.succeed message)


main : Program () Model Msg
main =
    Browser.sandbox
        { init = Good "https://developer.mozilla.org/static/arrows/arrow-right.cbc8b4f075cc.svg"
        , view = view
        , update = update
        }
```

[Ellie App](https://ellie-app.com/3YnWsRb9GJPa1).

I **init** the model with a *good* url "https://developer.mozilla.org/static/arrows/arrow-right.cbc8b4f075cc.svg", but if you somehow make it a *bad* url like "https://bad.developer.mozilla.org/static/arrows/arrow-right.cbc8b4f075cc.svg", you will the default image there.